# Characters disappearing in cygwin terminal

Tags: terminal, cygwin

In Windows, in both the Windows Terminal and cygwin's own terminal, sometimes with things like sftp and interactive php, some characters are 'disappearing' -- see the screenshot. This doesn't occur in a WSL2 session on the same machine, nor if I ssh to a Linux machine on my network, but does if I ssh to another Windows machine and invoke e.g. `php -a` inside a cygwin shell. So I'm guessing it's a cygwin problem, but what? (TERM is set to xterm-256color)

[image: Disappearing characters]

This is how it looks (correctly) within WSL:

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious to me what is different from what you expect to see. A screenshot of the expected appearance would help.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the expected behaviour. The 'hp >' characters are missing. And it gets worse when editing lines.

Comment: The best source of help for cygwin is the official `cygwin.com` mailing list. Subscribe to the list (so you will see replies) and post your question there (in plain text, not HTML) with the screenshots as attachments. Provide a step by step recipe that others can follow to reproduce the problem.